# Omit part of text file delimited by sentinel lines

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

Given a test file `settings.py`, looking like this:

```
# Django settings for x project.
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

I would like to programmatically (shell scripting) replace the part between line:

```
DATABASES = {
```

and:

```
}
```

with some text contained in variable `k`:

```
declare -r k='foo bar baz'
```

I am a `perl` beginner, but I concocted this:

```
perl -ne 'if(!$f && /DATABASES/){$f=1} if(!$f){print} if($f && /^}$/){$f=0}' < settings.py
```

which is a departure from my usual `sed`/`awk` little hacks:

```
# e.g.
sed '/DATABASES/,/^}$/ d' < settings.py
```

I'd like to improve my `perl` one-liners!

How can I do what `sed` does so beautifully in the almighty `perl`?

What's the absolute best way to:

- watch stdin pass by and reproduce it to stdout
- detect a sentinel "stop printing" line and halt copying
- re-enable pass-through of stdin->stdout upon encountering a 2nd sentinel line

I have omitted the *replacement* part of the task, hoping to get some help with that as well.

Comment: I think sed's `/DATABASES/,/^}$/` is rougly th same as [`/DATABASES/ ... /^}$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would show you how to convert an awk script to a Perl one.

So to start out, I took [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) [awk version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755052/omit-part-of-text-file-delimited-by-sentinel-lines/15766741#15766741) and sent it through [`a2p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html).

```
$ a2p
/DATABASES = {/ { skip=1 }
skip && /^}/    { skip=0; $0=k }
!skip
^d
```

Note that `^d` represents pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

```
#!/opt/perl-5.14.1/bin/perl
eval 'exec /opt/perl-5.14.1/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    if (/DATABASES = {/) {
    $skip = 1;
    }
    if ($skip && /^}/) {
    $skip = 0;
    $_ = $k;
    }
    print $_ if !$skip;
}
```

---

We can throw out the `eval 'exec ...` line. I doubt that you would ever need it.

Since we only need to process `k="$k"`, `eval '$'.$1.'$2;' ...` can be thrown out as well.
we just have to either set `$k` to `$ENV{k}` or replace the former with the latter. (Note that you will have to call `export k` for this to work. You could also just call it through `env k="$k" perl test.pl`)

Since the line gets [`chomp`ed](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), we either need to replace `print $_ if !$skip;` with `print $_, "\n" if !$skip;` or set [`$\`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5c) to `"\n"`. I think we can just get away without calling [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Also to prevent hard to find mistakes I am going to add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the beginning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $skip; # prevents printing when true
while (<>) {
  if (/DATABASES = {/) {
    $skip = 1;
  }
  if ($skip && /^}/) {
    $skip = 0;
    $_ = $ENV{k}."\n";
  }
  print $_ if !$skip;
}
```

---

I think we can mix in a `sed`'ism here. ([`...`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators))

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  if( my $r = /DATABASES = {/ ... /^}/ ){

    if( $r == 1 ){ # first time it matches
      print $ENV{k}, "\n";
    }

    next; # don't print
  }

  print;
}
```

---

The only thing is, I think the OP wanted to replace the text **between** `DATABASES = {` and `}`. So we have to add code to allow those two lines to be printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  if( my $r = /DATABASES = {/ ... /^}/ ){

    if( $r == 1 ){
      # append the replacement to the first line
      $_ .= $ENV{k}."\n";

    }elsif( $r !~ /E/ ){ # rest of the matches, except the last one
      next;
    }
  }

  print;
}
```

---

You know, I don't really like having to place the replacement text in an environment variable. How about placing it in the [`__DATA__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) section.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $replacement = do{ local $/; <DATA> }; # slurp
close DATA;

while (<>) {
  if( my $r = /DATABASES = {/ .. /^}/ ){
    if( $r == 1 ){
      $_ .= $replacement;
    }elsif( $r !~ /E/ ){
      next
    }
  }
  print;
}

__DATA__
<<< FOO >>>
```

Comment: Sh*t man, I should **pay** you for the learning I am getting here.. for **free**! Thanks, man! You are so generous with your knowledge.. inspiring! I'd wash your feet in gratitude! (although you may not like that, it's symbolic). How inspiring that you are self-taught too!!

Answer (score 2):

Can't imagine why you'd want to use perl for simple text manipulation as it's what awk was designed for and, like all good UNIX tools, awk does one thing and does it well.

With GNU awk:

```
$ k="<<<< foo >>>>"
$ gawk -v k="$k" -v RS='\0' '{sub(/DATABASES = {.*\n}/,k)}1' file
# Django settings for x project.
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
<<<< foo >>>>
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Explanation:

```
gawk
-v k="$k"     = set the awk variable k to the value of the shell variable k
-v RS='\0'    = set the Record Separator to the NULL string so gawk reads the whole file
'
{sub(/DATABASES = {.*\n}/,k)}     = replace the text between "DATABASES = {" and "}" at the start of a line inclusive with the contents of the awk variable k.
1     = set a true condition which invokes the default action of printing the current record (the whole file in this case)
' file
```

If you can't read the whole file at one time due to a memory constraint or if you just prefer this style or don't have GNU awk, modify the script to (untested):

```
$ awk -v k="$k" '
    /DATABASES = {/ { skip=1 }
    skip && /^}/    { skip=0; $0=k }
    !skip
  ' file
```

Hopefully what it does is obvious. Note that removing the setting of RS='\0' means the script is no longer gawk-specific.

If you need to keep the delimiting lines, that's just a tweak too:

```
$ awk -v k="$k" '
    skip && /^}/    { skip=0; print k }
    !skip
    /DATABASES = {/ { skip=1 }
  ' file
# Django settings for x project.
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DATABASES = {
<<<< foo >>>>
}
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I love `sed` and `awk`! Thanks a lot for you answer!! Answer: only because I am _learning_ `perl`, I still prefer `sed`/`awk` for these things!

Comment: Could you kindly "explain"/"expand" your one-liner? It is customary, when a nice and compact solution is offered, to add a "reading guide" to it, for the uninitiated, or the ones (like me) less skilled than you.

Comment: The point is though, if you want to learn perl you should first learn what it's good for (I don't know what that is but I'm sure there's something). Just "learning perl" sounds like the people who "learn sed" by coming up with all sorts of convoluted scripts containing arcane combinations of punctuation marks and single characters to do things that you CAN do in sed but simply should not.

Comment: @Robottinosino - explanation added.

Comment: I now admire your `awk` solution even more. It does have, unnecessarily if I am not mistaken, a totally different memory requirement than line-based filtering: are you not, perchance, gobbling up the whole text file just to regex substitute? I ask because the pattern does not lend itself to be scanned with a buffer (i.e. think about it: I can't know whether I will encounter a closing brace until the whole file potentially has been read). This to me is a fundamental difference is scanning style: string-based regex Vs line scanning with a flag set and unset based on encountering a sentinel...

Comment: I appreciate your answer and hope to be learning even more through an ensuing exchange of ideas and observations..

Comment: Regarding "learning perl for the wrong things": bear in mind that I only have high-school, I am a tollbooth worker, I study for pleasure and self improvement and I find reflecting on small issues both interesting and instructive. I may never have a job in computers this way but life is about the pleasure taken in the journey, not the milestones reached, right? ;)

Comment: @Robottinosino - yes, it does read the whole file. Usually that's not a problem, especially with code files which should not be particularly large or you have a modularity issue. It's actually a trivial tweak do handle one line at a time if that is an issue, though - I'll modify my answer to show an alternative.

Comment: According to [Larry Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall) [*It (Perl) combines (in  the  author's (Larry's) opinion,  anyway) some  of the best features of C, sed, awk, and sh.*](http://history.perl.org/PerlTimeline.html)

Comment: I love both (sed|awk) and perl, I am ignorant in both and would love to increase my understanding of both! :D

Comment: I went ahead and converted your final answer to [Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755052/omit-part-of-text-file-delimited-by-sentinel-lines/15774896#15774896) using [a2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html "perldoc a2p").

Comment: @Robottinosino - FYI sed and awk are 2 completely different tools, there is no sed/awk just like there's no grep/perl or cut/diff or whatever. One time a couple of guys wrote a book that discussed both sed & awk, I assume that's where the confusion comes in as you're not alone in considering them some kind of package deal.

Comment: Yeah, I am reading that book as an intro to the _dynamic duo_ :) You guessed right. :)

Comment: @BradGilbert - I really don't have anything against perl at all, I've just honestly never figured out what it's for. I use C for performance-critical SW, awk and the other standard UNIX tools for parsing text, and shell for manipulating files and processes. Assuming perl really does combine all of that, it's like having one huge woodworking power tool that saws, drills, and hammers - sounds cool but you'd never actually buy it since there's the smaller, more convenient, single-purpose tools readily available in every toolbox.

Comment: @Robottinosino - throw that book away and get Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins. You don't need a book to teach you how to use sed for the things you should use sed for (simple substitutions on a single line) and Arnolds new book is far more current and informative on awk than his old sed&awk book.

Comment: @Robottinosino - in case Brad's right in his perl answer and you want to keep the delimiting lines, I updated my answer to add an example of that in awk too. It's just another trivial, 3-line script, mainly just moving the conditions into the right order...

Comment: Perl is more like a well stocked tool shed where you only have to bring out the tools that are most appropriate for the job at hand, but the important thing is that the more different tools you have, the more likely one will be nearly perfect for the job. ( Perl has also been described as a Swiss Army Chainsaw ) For example if what you really need is a tack-hammer, a ball-peen hammer isn't really a good substitute.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the part between DATABASES and }, you can use this:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (/DATABASES/../^}$/)' settings.py
```

For the replacement, something like this:

```
$ export VAR="foo bar baz"
$ perl -ne 'print $ENV{VAR},"\n" if /DATABASES/; print unless /DATABASES/../^}$/' settings.py
```

Comment: Thanks.. how would you do the replacement, though?

Comment: Just print what you want if you see the first line of what you want to replace: `perl -ne 'print "$ENV{VAR}\n" if /DATABASES/; print unless /DATABASES/../^}$/' settings.py`

Comment: @aragaer : thanks mate, nice solution, updated it... my solution was looking funny once i saw yours :)